# Ember CLI - Injecting a service

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I created the following service and initializer using Ember CLI (generate blueprint):

```
// services/session.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    loggedIn: false,

    ...
});

// initializers/session.js
export default {
  name: 'session',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    app.inject('route', 'session', 'service:session');
    app.inject('controller', 'session', 'service:session');
  }
};
```

However, the session is undefined when attempting to access it in a route or controller. Am I missing a step?

```
// routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
        var loggedIn = this.session.get('loggedIn'); // undefined
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injected services are lazy loaded, you have to access them via a getter `this.get('session')` and not directly `this.session`.

Also, you may want to check out [Ember-Simple-Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) if you're doing authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it 99% correct, just seems like a problem with how you're accessing the session.

```
// routes/application.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
        var loggedIn = this.get('session.loggedIn');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am still getting undefined when attempting to use this method. I also tried this.get('session').get('loggedIn') without success.

Comment: @csm232s is `this.get('session')` defined?

Comment: Also, you may want to check out ember-simple-auth if you're doing authentication.

Comment: You can create an answer with this, that was the problem!